# What does case y :: ys mean?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make sense of the code below, but got stuck on `case y :: ys`. How is this defined? I don't see any declaration for `y`, and `ys`... Where do they come from?

I understand that `case` matches try to do equals on the object, but `case y :: ys` seems to be an operation. What is happening here?

```
def f(xs: List[Int], g: (Int, Int) => Boolean) = {
  def h(x: Int, xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
    xs match {
      case List() => List(x)
      case y :: ys => if (!g(x, y)) x :: xs else y :: h(x, ys)
    }
  (xs :\ List[Int]())(h)
}
```

Comment: You should read about [*pattern matching*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html). Here, if list `xs` has at least one element, then that element (the head of the list) gets bound to `y` and the rest (the tail of the list) gets bound to `ys`.

Comment: Yeah. Or, to answer your question directly - the double colon is called a cons operator, it's used on lists and it means head :: tail (since lists are implemented like that - each list is a recursive chain of head element and "the rest", which again consist of head and the rest etc. until you hit head :: Nil)

Comment: @Jubobs I had read that blog entry, but from it, I couldn't find the relation to this case here. However, your comments helped. It's still strange to me that the match is made on a `if the list has elements` logic, as it doesn't seem intuitive at all from the statement `y :: ys` that's what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't see any declaration for y, and ys, so where do they come from?

What you see *is* the declaration.

A case is able to deconstruct a value (here `xs`)  into its parts according to a pattern, if that "matches" (see it?).
Here a list is deconstructed into a head (giving it the name `y`) and a tail/rest (giving it the name `ys`). Those two parts can now be accessed separately in the expression after the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
case y :: ys =>
```

This is an equivalent of pattern matching for lists wherein your `x` matches with `head` of the list while `ys` matches with the `tail`. In pattern maching allows you to **de-structure** the input to match a given pattern, in this case a list with `y` as head and `ys` as tail

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers, `case y :: ys` matches `head`(y) and `tail`(ys) of a list.

It's actually a syntactic sugar,  `::` is a `case class`, you can check the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon) and `case y :: ys`
 equals to `case ::(y, ys)`.